# What is the difference between totally bounded and uniformly bounded?

Tags: analysis

Can somebody please explain me what the difference is between totally bounded and uniformly bounded functions?

Comment: Please formulate your question as a question.

Comment: Could you give the definitions, and where are the functions defined?

Answer (score 21):

To illustrate the concepts, I consider real functions in one real variable in the following. Of course this carries over to arbitrarly generalized contexts (domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$, metric spaces, Banach spaces, whatever).

A single function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is *bounded*, if there exists a constant $C\ge 0$ such that $|f(x)|\le C$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The term *uniformly bounded* only makes sense if you are considering an object that depends on at least one additional parameter, e.g. a sequence of functions $(f_k)_k$ ($f_k(x)$ depends on the index $k$ and on $x$).

A sequence $(f_k:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R})_k$ of functions is *uniformly bounded* if there exists a constant $C\ge 0$ s.t. for all $k$ we have $|f_k(x)|\le C$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
The important thing here is that **C does not depend on $x$**. This is what the word *uniformly* means.

In contrast, such a sequence is *(pointwise) bounded*, if for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a constant $C=C(x)\ge 0$ such that $|f_k(x)|\le C$ for all $k$. Here, $C$ depends on $x$.

Uniformly bounded means each of the functions in the set is bounded with respect to the sup metric if we are talking about a metric space.

Comment: What if $C$ does not depend on $x$ but does depend on $k$?